# Destroy user session from cron job

Tags: php

I'm building a captive portal (host spot for internet browsing). I would like to destroy sessions from a background job and logout the user from the page after time expiration.

I'm confused as to how to do it. In general, session destruction has to be coded into the same page as where the user logs in, but I want to destroy the session from a cron job for logged-in users after a specific time.

Is there a way to pass some variables to a PHP script running under cron to destroy the session and logout the user?

Comment: If you rely on a database to store sessions you can remove the record from the db and then tell your code to kill session if it doesn't exist in the db where it expected it to be

Answer (score 1):

If you use php's default sessions storage, which is file, you will not be able to do what you want.
What you need is to save your sessions into database, there are many php classes that will do exactly this job. Once the session is in database, each session row will have a user id associated (populate at login) and a timestamp with the last activity.
Based on these two columns, you can delete the user sessions from any cronjob you have.

Comment: what about just deleting session files with crontab? smth like `-mtime +30 -exec rm {}`

Comment: "you will not be able to do what you want", why? its just files that apache can read

Comment: usually the sessions will be stored in `/tmp` under various names, but beside the session files, you also have other temp files there, wouldn't be nice to delete those too (even with right permissions). Next it comes down to performance vs accesibility. Whereas a database access is easy to get, a shell access is difficult

Comment: easy answer there is to change the session save paath

Comment: what if he needs to delete only a particular user session? scan n files, read them and then remove the correct one? why go through all the trouble ?

Comment: yes exactly I need to destroy particular session and logoff the user from the page.
Is this possible even if I use database?
Im using database to store username and password.

Comment: then go with the database solution, is the best you have.

Comment: If I delete the user session from the database is going to logging him off the page where he logged in?

Comment: Thats up to your code, but most code that use sessoins stored in database, ignore the session if its not in the database = logged out

Answer (score 1):

where do you stote the sessions?

if it's in serialized files in the /tmp/ folder (default)
then you can use:

```
foreach(scandir('/tmp/') as $session_file)
{
   if(substr($session_file, 0, 5) != 'sess_')
   {
       // not a sessoin file
       continue;
   }

   // load sessoin
   $current_session = unserialize(file_get_contents('/tmp/' .  $session_file));

   // do some tests
   if($current_session['abc'] == 'def')
   {
       // store somthing in it
       $current_session['ghi'] = 'jkl';
       file_put_contents('/tmp/' .  $session_file, serialize($current_session));

       // or delete the session file
       unlink('/tmp/' .  $session_file);
   }
}
```

Comment: why doing this when database sessions will ease his work dozens times? Also, your solution is way slower than database access, if he cares about performance, your solution should be dropped from the start.

Comment: yes, if there is a database avaible, that whould be faster, but that also requires the current code to be updated to use the database, but as he asked for somthing for a cronjob, i gave a solution that dosn't require a database and dosn't require changes in the current sourcecode

Comment: see also my other comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864735/destroy-user-session-from-cron-job/16864856?noredirect=1#comment24326469_16864789

Comment: Yes, your soultion is faster, if the needed changes is posible.

Comment: I need to destroy particular session for the user and logging him off the page is this possible with your code ?

Comment: how do you define the "particular session"? guess the row if($current_session['abc'] == 'def') can be modified to find that one

Answer (score 0):

Your best best would probably be the database.

Store user session_id's with their creation time and expiration time. Then just run cron job on your CLI class and check database for expired sessions list then just delete them from server (location depends on your php setup).
Also mark them as invalid in database once you remove it, that would make session invalid.

Of Course you would have to change your code a bit to test if session exists that user is presenting.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck making a file on the server called something like force_session_expire.php  that looks like this

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1); 
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
session_start();
?>

This makes it so there is a 1 in 1 chance that you will kick off garbage collection. then you start the session so the garbage collection will be done.
```

in whatever command scheduler you are using and kick it off hourly (via a wget or curl call).